# Georeferencing labels in QGIS

Tags: qgis

Is there a way to geo-reference labels alongside the points in the shapefile in QGIS?  Usually this would not be necessary as labelling in print composer works just fine, but in this case I need to transfer the entire shapefile (points and lines along with labels) into CUBE

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `$x` and `$y` formulas in the attribute table.

But first, you have to check your coordinate system. For exemple, if I have a project in Lambert-93 (RFG93), I add two new columns in the attributes table and apply the formula `$x` and `$y` to each of them : my points have now labels with longitude and latitude.